# I am having troubles creating a Marker on flutter with the Google Maps dependency

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, google-maps, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to create an app in flutter that allows me to find electoral zones by 4 digit codes,

but I am having problems when passing data from one screen to another to use the variable that I

pass globally.

```
                        return new ListView(
                              children: snapshot.data.documents
                                  .map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                                return new ListTile(
                                    title: Text(document['estado']),
                                    onTap: () {
                                      Navigator.of(context).push(
                                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                                          return Mapita(document['lng'],document['lat']);
                                        }),
                                      );
                                    });
                              }).toList());
```

I found a tutorial with this code that I am trying to modify, my problem is that I want to change the numbers that come in the line that correspond to longitude and latitude "LatLng currentLocation = LatLng(16.8526229, -99.8180829); " by the final data Strings latitude and longitude that I get from the previous screen so I can display a marker with the data that I provide from a specific location.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart' as lct;

class Mapita extends StatefulWidget {
  final String latitud;
  final String longitud;
  Mapita(this.latitud, this.longitud);

  @override
  _MapitaState createState() => _MapitaState();
}

class _MapitaState extends State<Mapita> {
  LatLng currentLocation = LatLng(16.8526229, -99.8180829);
  GoogleMapController _mapController;
  lct.Location location;
  BitmapDescriptor icon;

  @override
  void initState(){
    requestPerms();
    super.initState();
  }

  getLocation() async{
    var currentLocation = await location.getLocation();
    locationUpdate(currentLocation);
  }


  locationUpdate(currentLocation){
    if(currentLocation!= null){
      setState(() {
        this.currentLocation =
            LatLng(currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude);
        this._mapController.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
          CameraPosition(target: this.currentLocation, zoom: 14),
        ));
        _createMarker();
      });
    }
  }


  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller){
    _mapController = controller;
  }

  changedLocation(){
    location.onLocationChanged.listen((lct.LocationData cLoc) {
      if(cLoc != null) locationUpdate(cLoc);
    });
  }

// Pedir permiso de Ubicacion
  requestPerms() async {
    Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> statuses =
    await [Permission.locationAlways].request();

    var status = statuses[Permission.locationAlways];
    if (status == PermissionStatus.denied) {
      requestPerms();
    } else {
      gpsAnable();
    }
  }

//Activar GPS
  gpsAnable() async {
    location = lct.Location();
    bool statusResult = await location.requestService();

    if (!statusResult) {
      gpsAnable();
    } else {
      /*getLocation();
      changedLocation();
      */
    }
  }

//crear Marker
  Set<Marker> _createMarker() {
    var marker = Set<Marker>();

    marker.add(Marker(
      markerId: MarkerId("MarkerCurrent"),
      position: currentLocation,
      icon: icon,
      infoWindow: InfoWindow(
        title: "Casilla electoral",
        snippet: "Latitud ${currentLocation.latitude} - Longitud ${currentLocation.longitude} ",
      ),
    ));

    return marker;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF840B55),
        title: Text("Instituto Nacional Electoral"),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          GoogleMap(
            initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
              target: currentLocation,
              zoom: 14.0,
            ),
            myLocationEnabled: true,
            myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
            minMaxZoomPreference: MinMaxZoomPreference(12, 25),
            markers: _createMarker(),
            onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: please reduce your code, to precisely where the error is occuring.

Comment: I just want to pass the data from the first screen to the second screen through the page route and be able to use it globally in the second screen or rather where LatLng currentLocation is declared, replace the numbers that remain fixed by the variables latitude and longitude.